# How to declare a method pointer as a typedef method parameter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a method typedef which includes a pointer parameter of the method type itself - is this possible?

A method would look something like:

```
void myFunc(FuncType* pFunc, int a) {}
```

where `myFunc` is a declaration that matches `FuncType`, so I could set a variable and call it like this:

```
FuncType f = myFunc;
f(&f, 5);
```

I've tried to declare a typedef matching this method as:

```
typedef void (*FuncType)(FuncType*, int);
```

But this doesn't work because `FuncType` is required before it is fully declared. I can fix this by setting the parameter to a void pointer, but is there some way around this; perhaps through some form of forward declaration of `FuncType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible; a function can't take a parameter of its own type (or return such a thing).
This is the case for all reasonably powerful type systems.

The only workaround is to introduce an indirection through another type, as you did with `void*`.

It's analogous to how a class can't contain an instance of itself as a member, which you work around by indirecting through a pointer or reference.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I thought by declaring the parameter as a pointer to the type, I could get away with it in the same way as structs and classes do. Obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you *NOT* declare such a `typedef`, you cannot declare such a function either. It results in infinite recursion.

Here's how such a function declaration would look like:

```
void myFunc(void (*pFunc)(...), int a);
```

where `...` would expand to:

```
void (*pFunc)(...), int)
```

where `...` would expand to:

```
void (*pFunc)(...), int)
```

Comment: Where's the recursion? All I'm doing is calling a function and passing it a pointer and an integer.

Comment: @adelphus The "recursion" is at the type level, not in the function itself.

Comment: OK, I get it. The reason I disagree is that the parameter is a **pointer** to the type, not the type itself. It's how you can declare structs and classes to contain a member of themselves - you declare a pointer to the struct or class and the type system manages to sort it out.

Comment: @adelphus, unfortunately, you cannot do that. Your only option is to use `void*` and cast the argument before using it to make a function call.